# Is there a trick to make GCC optimize away redundant instructions?

Tags: c, gcc, arm

Compiling with `gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -Os`
emits redundant instructions like in this illustrative example:

```
void memzero(void* p, int n)
{
    n -= 4;
    do
    {
        *(int*)((char*)p + n) = 0;
        n -= 4;
    }
    while(n > 0);
}
```

Results in:

```
memzero:
  movs r3, #0
  subs r1, r1, #4
.L2:
  str r3, [r0, r1]
  subs r1, r1, #4
  cmp r1, #0
  bgt .L2
  bx lr
```

Obviously, the explicit compare is essentially a nop. Is there some way to turn on more optimization to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure how obvious your "obviously" claim is.  Does anything change if you use `-O3` or `-O2` or some other optimization flag?

Comment: How about using `memset()`?

Comment: BTW; your funcion name is illegal. Function names starting with"mem" or "str" are reserved

Comment: clang/llvm produces a similar result, not as optimized but subtracts then compares.

Comment: examine some of the memset implementations for thumb and reverse them to fill down if you want something optimized.

Comment: This is quite fishy code no matter. You need to worry about alignment and strict aliasing both.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes - it's an "illustrative example". So any ideas on getting GCC to optimize away that redundant compare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the compare would change the behavior of the function.

The `BGT` instruction jumps if `Z == 0 and N == V`. This is important when `n` overflows.

Consider calling the function with `n = -2147483644` (if `int` is 32 bit):

```
memzero:
        movs    r3, #0
        subs    r1, r1, #4    ; n = -2147483648
.L2:
        str     r3, [r0, r1]
        subs    r1, r1, #4    ; n = 2147483644, Z = 0, N = 0, V = 1
        ;cmp     r1, #0       ; (would set Z = 0, N = 0, V = 0)
        bgt     .L2           ; doesn't jump, even though n is positive
        bx      lr
```

The optimization works if we test for `n >= 0` because there is an instruction that jumps if `N == 0`:

```
memzero:
        movs    r3, #0
        subs    r1, r1, #4
.L2:
        str     r3, [r0, r1]
        subs    r1, r1, #4
        bpl     .L2
        bx      lr
```

#### Test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

__attribute__((noinline)) int with_cmp(int n) {
    asm("L1:\n\t"
        "subs    %[n], #4\n\t"
        "cmp     %[n], #0\n\t"
        "bgt     L1"
        : [n] "+r" (n));
    return n;
}

__attribute__((noinline)) int without_cmp(int n) {
    asm("L2:\n\t"
        "subs    %[n], #4\n\t"
        "bgt     L2"
        : [n] "+r" (n));
    return n;
}

int main() {
    printf("with cmp: %d\nwithout cmp: %d\n", with_cmp(INT_MIN), without_cmp(INT_MIN));
}
```

Output:

```
with cmp: 0              // loops as long as n > 0
without cmp: 2147483644  // immediately returns with positive n
```

Comment: With that fix, the function still doesn't clear the first n%4 bytes, so it only works if n%4==0. (And sizeof(int) == 4).

Comment: not to mention the alignment problems.  which are fine when n%4 = 0 and *p is aligned.

Comment: I tested on x86 and ARM and there were no alignment problems.

Comment: There's no bug. It's an "illustrative example". But now we know GCC can optimize away the redundant compare in case of <= or >=, while it can't in case of < , > or !=. Very strange. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
+6 nzCv nzCv
+5 nzCv nzCv
+4 nZCv nZCv
+3 Nzcv NzCv
+2 Nzcv NzCv
+1 Nzcv NzCv
+0 Nzcv NzCv
-1 NzCv NzCv
-2 NzCv NzCv
-3 NzCv NzCv
```

are the flag choices through the sub and cmp operations for that value of N.  When N hits 4 the code tells it to stop.  4-4 = 0  stop when N <= 0.

```
+4 nZCv nZCv
```

so signed BGT Z = 0, N == V is a choice, but yes that does work for both subs and the cmp.  This is a missed peephole optimization which you are free to investigate or report. I can't imagine this has not been reported to date, unless it was recently added unintentionally.

```
+3 Nzcv NzCv
```

is what is mentioned in another answer where if the comparison is changed to N != 0 then the N flag alone determines the boundary.

If you try this you can do an incrementing loop and still run into this.  I believe we have seen this asked at Stack Overflow before, I don't know what to look for.  Perhaps that one it didn't appear to be a possible optimization.

Comment: I called it a NOP because it doesn't change the machine state. By your standard, NOPs don't exist in modern ISAs. Anyway, thanks for your answer, though it's hard to believe something this trivial is overlooked by the optimizer. >= and <= is optimized. > , < and != aren't. Very strange.

Comment: fair enough this isa doesnt have a nop if I recall an xor r0,r0 or something like that is used, I would have to look it up again.  add zero, mov a register to itself (that might be what gas and others use, not sure), thumb usually doesnt offer a dont change the flags option like arm does.  will have to look, point taken though.

Comment: gnu assembler generates 0x4c60 which is a mov r8,r8 according to objdump (and by decoding based on the arm arm).  armv6-m shows 0xBF00 as a nop. or a nop-hint.   (as does armv7-m)  the armv4t/v5t era arm arm does not specifically define a nop in the instruction list.  and goes further to say: Any instruction with bits[15:12] = 1011, and which is not shown in Figure 6-2, is an undefined instruction.  where 11:8 = 4b1111 is not shown.